Display error: screen gets divided or shown with offset - Arch Linux - desktop manager
I have installed Arch Linux in a Lenovo tablet. The resolution and the image is good, but som times (apparently when I have not interacted with the screen in a while) the screen gets divided or splitted. Leaving an inch of the top part of the screen at the bottom.
It corrects it self after some seconds or when I interact (click or touch) the top part of the screen (the physical top part, no the imagen corresponding to the top part)
Example of screen
I don't know if this is related but I managed to get the touchscreen working by changing the TransformationMatrix in a file in xorg.d directory.
Section   "InputClass"
    Identifier "Goodix Capacitive TouchScreen"
    MatchIsPointer "on"
    Driver "libinput"
    Option "TransformationMatrix" "0 1 0 -1 0 1 0 0 1"
EndSection

I don't know if it useful but these ar som outputs for lspci -v:
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation GeminiLake [UHD Graphics 600] (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 39ff
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 126
Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
I/O ports at 1000 [size=64]
Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915

The output for uname -r
6.11.5-arch1-1

Update December 03
I've tested other Display Managers (before I had lightdm) like SDDM but the problem continues. I thought it could be the problem because the cursor is shown properly all the time. Maybe its not the display output but the "GUI manager?".
I tried another desktop managers too. I can see an improvement using openbox. By improvement I mean it's less frequents and it corrects itself quicker (almost on a blink of an eye).
End of update
I really don't know other way to describe this problem. I you need any other detail please let me know.
Thanks in advance
